How to fix HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
I am trying to publish ASP.NET Core MVC web app to Windows Server 2019, using IIS. I am using a very basic web app for testing.
When I try to browse the site from IIS Manager, I get this error:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related > configuration data for the page is invalid
Error Code    0x8007000d
Config File   \?\C:\GcTest\web.config

I suspect one of these three problems, but don't know how to solve them:

Maybe the config file path \\?\C:\GcTest\web.config is not valid

I installed ASP.NET 4.8, when I browse the Roles and Features in the Server Manager, I only get ASP.NET 4.7:


In IIS, Sites->Default Web Site -> Modules, AspNetCoreModuleV2 is missing.




Errors 500 always mean: "Look at the logs on your server for details". Always. Could be Windows Event Viewer, your application log or e.g. the output of Failed Request Tracing. For ASP.NET Core I could imagine that you did not install the Hosting Bundle but this is pure guessing; looking at the error details should give you more insights.

Finally got it, I had the wrong version of the Hosting Bundle... Thanks @UweKeim

open specific site folder,in properties  to the Security tab.give full permission to IIS_IUSRS.and recycle app fool
